# User Inputs Value, but Arbitrary Value Printed to Screen. Printed Value doesn't Match Entered Value

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
//class definition
class BankCustomer
{
public:
    BankCustomer();     //constructor for BankCust class
    void fullname(string, string);
    string firstname();
    string lastname();
    bool setsocial(int s); //accept a arg. of int type
    int getsocial();
private:
    string fname, lname; 
    int SSNlength;  //can't be changed by client; sensitive info should be made private
};

//class implementation
BankCustomer::BankCustomer(){}

void BankCustomer::fullname(string f, string l)
{
    fname=f;
    lname=l;
}

string BankCustomer::firstname()
{
    return fname;
}

string BankCustomer::lastname()
{
    return lname;
}

bool BankCustomer::setsocial(int s)
{
    int count, SSNlength;
    while(s != 0)
    {
        s /=10;             //counts number of integers; count goes to max of ten
        ++count;
        if(count == 9)
        {
            cout <<"\nValid SSN Entered!" << endl;
            SSNlength=s;
            return true;
        }
    }
}

int BankCustomer::getsocial()
{
    return SSNlength;
}

//client program
int main()
{
    BankCustomer customer;          //customer declared as object of BankCust class
    string firstname, lastname;
    int ssn, s;

    //data assignment
    cout <<"\n Enter First Name\n" << endl;
    cin >> firstname;

    cout<<"\n Enter Last Name\n"<< endl;
    cin >> lastname;

    customer.fullname(firstname,lastname);

    do
    {
        cout<<"\nEnter 9-Digit SSN"<< endl;
        cin >> ssn;
    }
    while(!customer.setsocial(ssn)); //function will repeat as long as entered user ssn forces social() to evaluate it as false

    //data ouput
    cout <<"\nFirst Name:  "<<customer.firstname()<<"\n"<< endl;
    cout <<"\nLast Name:  "<<customer.lastname()<<"\n"<< endl;
    cout <<"\n SSN is:  "<<customer.getsocial()<<"\n" << endl;      //not printing correct value
}
```

When I run the program, entered user input of first and last name is printed correctly to screen. However, when I try to print entered value of SSN, the program gives back a garbage value that doesn't match the one user entered. Issue occurs when return value of `customer.getsocial()` is printed on `cout<<"\n SSN is:` line.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to step through your code, one line at a time, and you examined the values of all variables, at each step of the way, what observations have you made? What happened to the parameter that's passed to `setsocial()`, and what happened when you examined, in the debugger, the value of the class member where the data is supposed to be stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your member variable SSNlength is unintialized, while you define a local variable with the same name in setsocial(int s) at

```
int count, SSNlength;
```

Thus, your member variable will not be initialized as your local variable hides it, which means that getsocial() will always return garbage ...

Also, you should return false from setsocial(int s) if your input **s** is not valid to avoid undefined behaviour. May be something like

```
bool BankCustomer::setsocial(int s)
{
  SSNlength = s;
  int count;
  while(s != 0)
  {
    s /=10;
    ++count;
    if(count == 9)
    {
       cout <<"\nValid SSN Entered!" << endl;
       return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Ok. I took out the declaration of SSNlength in setsocial(). When I run the program again, now I'm not getting a garbage value. But now instead of the 9-digit value I enter, I just get 'SSN is: 0'. It's a start!

Comment: that's expected !! you have a while loop that actually make sure that **s** is zero before SSNlength = s .. may be do SSNlength = s before the loop..

Comment: modified my code and it works like a charm. i do understand more of why i kept getting a garbage value. I guess when it comes to C++, define everything explicitly like it's a dumb robot haha